# JavaScript Bar Chart with Date Range selection

Tags: javascript, ajax, charts

I am looking for a JavaScript Date Range plug-in, where I can load all data in at once, and then just filter it by JavaScript. I have been looking around, but can't seem to find a library, hope I am missing one or two.

I am trying to get this to reduce AJAX calls. Its not quite hard to combine a datepicker to any barchart plug-in, but I don't like AJAX calls that aren't necessary.